Uncaught Exception: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'format')
I've been having trouble with sending the video files to be read by ffprobe. I have fluent-ffmpeg and ffprobe installed but this error shows. I'm not sure what I'm missing
index.js
const electron = require('electron')
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = electron
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
let mainWindow
// const ffmpeg = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg');
// app.on('ready', function(){
//     console.log('App is ready')
// })
app.on('ready', function(){
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences:{
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false
        }
    })
    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
})

ipcMain.on('video:submit', (event, path)=>{
    ffmpeg.ffprobe(path, (err, metadata)=>{
        let duration = metadata.format.duration
        console.log(err)
        mainWindow.webContents.send(
            'video:metadata',
            duration
        )
    })
})

index.html
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Video info</h1>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label>Select new video</label>
            <input type="file" accept="video/*">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Get info"/>
    </form>
    <h1 id="result"></h1>
    <script>
        const electron = require('electron')
        const {ipcRenderer} = electron
        document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (event)=>{
            event.preventDefault()
            const {path} = document.querySelector('input').files[0]
            ipcRenderer.send('video:submit', path)
        })

        ipcRenderer.on('video:metadata', (event,duration)=>{
            document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML =  `Video duration is ${duration} seconds`
        })
    </script>
</body>

I tried to reinstall and udpate the ffmpeg nodes but the error still persists

Disregard this, it's solved. I solved it by restarting my computer
